# In Angular, using PrimeNG, how to set some p-selectButton options disabled?

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using `<p-selectButton>` a lot and I need sometimes for some of its options to be disabled. How to do that? In my `graphManager.ts` I have:

```
graphTypes: Array<SelectItem> = [
            {label: 'bar', value: 'bar', disabled : true },
            {label: 'line', value: 'line', disabled : false},
];

selectedGraphType: SelectItem = this.graphTypes[0];
```

Then, in `graphManager.html` I have:

```
<p-selectButton class="customSelector select-button-big ui-button-rounded"
              [options]="graphTypes" 
              [(ngModel)]="selectedGraphType"
              (onChange)="setSelectedGraphType($event)" >
</p-selectButton>
```

I have my custom `SelectItem.ts` :

```
export interface SelectItem {
    label?: string;
    value: any;
    styleClass?: string;
    icon?: string;
    title?: string;
    disabled?: boolean;
}
```

But the options are all still available for clicking. How can I disable some options for selection? What only worked is digging into `node_modules/primeng/components/selectbutton/selectbutton.js` and changing line 55:

```
SelectButton.prototype.onItemClick = function (event, option, checkbox, index) {
        if (this.disabled || option.disabled) {
```

So I added the `|| option.disabled` part. You will however agree that this is not acceptable option, since it changes the node_modules. However it is the only things that worked for me.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried putting a non existant option for its [(ngModel)]="graphType", so I tried setting up graphType='';
Didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

You just have to add [disabled]="true"  ,

```
<p-button icon="pi pi-check" [disabled]="true" label="Disabled"></p-button>
```

**Edit**

*About p-selectButton*

Particular options can be prevented from selection using the disabled property of SelectItem API.

**Example**

```
cards: SelectItem[];

this.cards= [
            {label: 'Paypal', value: 'PayPal', disabled : true },
            {label: 'Visa', value: 'Visa', disabled : false},
            {label: 'MasterCard', value: 'MasterCard', disabled : false}
        ];
```

Comment: This makes ALL the options disabled. I only want certain options, not all, to be disabled.

Comment: Excuse me, I meant <p-selectButton> I changed the original question.

Comment: Can you please give an example of how to do it? Where do i use the SelectItem, and how?

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic Example added mate

Comment: great, is there a way to do this witout having to change the node_modules?

Comment: you dont need to change node_modules

Comment: because when I mention SelectItems to Angular, it offers me to add the import, and the imported SelectItem is actually inside the node_modules.

Comment: SelectItem  is already there inside **primeng node_module**, your just importing it. Not changing node modules mate

Comment: but my SelectItem inside node_modules does not have the disabled field.

Comment: Check this https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/common/selectitem.ts

Comment: I don't know how to change the individual options on the fly, and not only during the init.

Comment: when your populating the array which is passed to p-selectButton add **disabled:true**

Comment: you will have to edit your question with details of what your trying

Comment: I'm tried all these and not of these worked. It will disabled ALL the options not just the ones that you want. And you are correct, @VladimirDespotovic you will have to create a custom SelectItem interface. did you solve your question?